# Infinite times a strictly positive bounded function

Tags: limits

When computing the limit of a product of two functions, one of which is strictly positive and bounded, as $\cos x +2$ for example, and the limit of the other is $\infty$, the limit of the product is $\infty$. Is there any theorem or proof that sustains that?

Comment: Just being strictly positive won't do. You need that factor to be strictly positive and bounded away from zero.

Comment: Also such results are trivial applications of basic definitions of limits and the usual limit theorems and hence are not provided as separate theorems. You should try to prove it by using definition of limit.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x) =|\cos(x)| + 1/x$ and $g(x)=x$. Then $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) g(x) $ does not exist (just consider the two sequences $x_n=n \pi$ and $y_n=\pi n + \pi/2$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $f$ is not strictly positive. Replace $f$ by $|\cos x|+1/x$.

Comment: Thanks, the $1/x$ remained in my fingers.

Comment: $|\cos x|+1/x$ is not strictly positive (lower bound, if any, is not above zero) either.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} x\, (\cos x+2) = \infty$. The point is -any theorem for this?

Comment: Then take $|\cos(x)| + 1/|x|$, it does not really change the underlying idea of the counterexample. What you need is something stronger, you need the bounded function to "stay uniformly away from $0$".

Comment: OK, we need the bounded function to have only a lower bound greater than zero. How to prove the limit of the product is $\infty$?